# Where can I find elastic beanstalk "instance health for details"

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've got a beanstalk environment with health warnings:

[image]

As you can see, it is tells me to "See instance health for details."

I can't find "instance health" anywhere, and my google fu is failing me.

[image]

Does anybody know how I can find out why beanstalk thinks my app is not healthy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to [install](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install.html) the `eb` command and then run `eb init`.  Once I did that, I could do `eb health` and I got a report.

[image]

Comment: The console does not show instance health right now. You can use the eb cli or if you prefer programmatically using DescribeInstancesHealth API: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/api/API_DescribeInstancesHealth.html